# Event timeline in No Longer human - Is my event order right?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

I've seen this page of *No longer human, from Osamu Dazai*

> God, I ask you, is non-resistance  a sin? I **had wept** at that incredible smile Horiki showed me, and forgetting both prudence and resistance, I **had got** into the car that **took** me here. And now I **had become** a madman. Even if released, I would be branded on the forehead with the word "madman", or perhaps, "reject". No longer human. I **had now ceased** utterly to be a human being.

Unfortunately, I don't know whether my event timeline is right - Because Past Perfect at every 10 words or so confuses me. - , and I wanted to show you to see if it's right.

**1st** - *Horiki showed a smile;*

**2nd** - He wept;

**3rd** - *He got into a car that took him to another place (in which he still is);*

**4th**- Become a mad man;

**5th** - Be no longer a human;

Have I gotten it right?

Comment: All those Past Perfect  verb forms are "correct", because they're all actions that happened before "**now**" (which in this text refers to *the "narrative reference time" in the **past***, rather *time of utterance / speaking / writing* as is usual). So you can't really fault the translator here. But even though I don't see any problem with the *sequence* of events (more a matter of logic than of language), I think it's stylistically clumsy (I'd probably just use Simple Past for all but the *final* PP form).

Comment: ...btw - it's meaningless to attempt to assign a "chronological sequence" to *becoming a madman* and *being lo no longer human* as if these were two distinct "events" in time. That to me is evidence that you're ***over-analysing*** the temporal implications of the actual ***words***, to the point that you're imagining possible distinctions that couldn't even *mean* anything in the real world.